# can't access to members of ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I want to get the products which are connect to my form like:['shirt' , 'hat']
but this gives me the bound method Manager insted of Queryset.

`models.py:`

```
from django.db import models
from eshop_product.models import Product

class Form(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=600, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=600, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
```

`views.py:`

```
def checkOut(request):
    user = request.user
    products = Form.objects.filter(user_name=user.username)[0].products.all
    for product in products:
        print(product.title)
```

This is the returned error:

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it in view, not in template, so try doing with [`all()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#all) method rather than only <s>`all`</s>, so try this view:

views.py

```
def checkOut(request):
    user = request.user
    products = Form.objects.filter(user_name=user.username)[0].products.all()
    for product in products:
        print(product.title)
```

> `Note:` `Form` is an in-built class in forms library, so change its name from <s>`Form`</s> to something like `UserForm` or anything suits to you.